# Using jQuery ajax call asp.net MVC action by JavaScript settimeout always stop and not working after running 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, settimeout

When playing video in the foreground of ASP.NET MVC 5, use setTimeout to invoke operations via jQuery ajax to increase the user's browsing time every 10 seconds.

At present, only 10 minutes have been recorded to stop. Is the reason for the browser to go to sleep (sleep)? If so, is there a way to prevent or resolve the browser from going to sleep so that setTimeout continues to execute? Or for other reasons?

I posted some code to clarify the problem:

_PlayVideo.cshtml

```
var d1 = new Date();        
d1.setHours(0, 0, 0);  
var t = 0;
var number = 0;

function RecordTime() {
        var h = d1.getHours();
        var m = d1.getMinutes();
        var s = d1.getSeconds();

        d1.setSeconds(d1.getSeconds() + 1);

        t = setTimeout(RecordTime, 1000);
        if (s == 10) {
            number++;
            d1.setHours(0, 0, 1); 
            var video = document.getElementById("my-video");
            RecordLearning(10, video.currentTime);
            console.log("currentTime: " + video.currentTime + " || number: " + number + " || Timer: " + new Date());
        }
    }


    function RecordLearning(time, currentTime) {
        var videoId = $("#videoId").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("_RecordLearning")",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                videoId: videoId,
                time: time,
                currentTime: currentTime
            },
        })
    .done(function (partialViewResult) {
        console.log("db connectioned");
    });
    }
```

CourseControler.cs

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    CollegeModel db = new CollegeModel();
    // GET: Course
    ......
   ...............
   ..............................

     public PartialViewResult _RecordLearning(int videoId, int time, float currentTime)
    {
        try
        {
            var memberIdString = Utility.GetLoginMemberId();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberIdString))
            {
                var video = db.Videos.Where(x => x.Id == videoId).First();
                LearningRecord record = null;
                var memberId = int.Parse(memberIdString);
                var records = from o in db.LearningRecords
                              where o.VideoId == video.Id &&
                                o.MemberId == memberId
                              select o;
                DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
                if (records.Count() > 0)
                {
                    record = records.First();
                    record.LengthCount += time;
                    record.LengthString = Utility.GetCourseLengthString(record.LengthCount);
                    record.CurrentTime = currentTime;
                    record.UpdateOn = dtNow;
                }
                else
                {
                    record = new LearningRecord();
                    record.MemberId = memberId;
                    record.CourseId = video.CourseId;
                    record.VideoId = videoId;
                    record.LengthCount = time;
                    record.LengthString = Utility.GetCourseLengthString(time);
                    record.CurrentTime = currentTime;
                    record.IsDelete = false;
                    record.CreateOn = dtNow;
                    db.LearningRecords.Add(record);
                }

                var member = db.Members.Where(x => x.Id == memberId).First();
                int totalLearningCount = 0;
                if (member.TotalLearningCount == null) member.TotalLearningCount = 0;

                member.TotalLearningCount += time;
                totalLearningCount = int.Parse(member.TotalLearningCount.ToString());
                member.TotalLearningString = Utility.GetCourseLengthString(totalLearningCount);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Execution to nearly 10 minutes (10 seconds a time about 60 times stopped). Whether in the peak period while watching the film 20 to 30 people or from the peak period 2 to 3 people are close to 10 minutes (600 seconds) is no longer record.

Comment: Are you saying that the `RecordLearning` doesn't get called by `RecordTime` after 10 minutes ?

Comment: I've just run a version of this (the timer part, obviously can't easily recreate the ajax), but it ran for 20 minutes without stopping, logging all the time. So the timer script is not the issue. Try logging exceptions on the server to see if something is going wrong there - currently your code hides all exceptions in the empty `catch` block - you should log them to the event log from there, and then re-throw them. And in the JS ajax call you should handle the `fail` function and log the error returned, so you can see if a particular client's calls are failing for any reason.